# React-native: Handling multiple element selection while using redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I have 8 `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` elements in a grid form. They are **not** dynamically rendered using map.
 this.props.selectCell('rain')}>

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={()=>this.props.selectCell('rain')}>                             
    <Row  style={[styles.orangish,styles.cell]}>                        
        <Image source={Rain} />
    </Row>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

The idea is to select one onPress.

**action**

```
export const selectCell = (cellId) => {
    console.log(cellId);
    return {
        type: 'select_cell',
        payload: cellId
    };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export default (state= {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'select_cell': {
      //trying to figure out what to do here


  }
};
```

1) How do I toggle the selection in reducer?

2) How to I render the a new image based on the state?

Comment: Please post code so we can ensure a correct response. Each item will need a unique id. Further code is needed to answer the other question

Comment: I have edited my question to be more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a selectedCellId property in the reducer state and set it as follows:

```
export default (state= {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'select_cell': {
      return {
         ...state,
         selectedCellId: action.payload
     };    
  }
};
```

An alternative is to have an array of 8 cells with selected = false.

```
const defaultState = {
  cells: [
    { selected: false },
    { selected: false },
    { selected: false },
    { selected: false },
    { selected: false },
    { selected: false },
    { selected: false },
    { selected: false }
  ]
};
```

Then in the reducer,

```
export default (state= defaultState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'select_cell': {
      let { cells } = state;
      cells = cells.slice();
      cells[action.payload] = { selected: true };
      return {
         ...state,
         cells
     };    
  }
};
```

If you have named cells, then make the cells collection an object map instead of an array.

Comment: How do I toggle the selection?

Comment: In the UI, you can compare the cellId with selectedCellId to make the toggle.

Comment: Updated answer with another alternative.